# Javascript: How to reload entire frameset onload() event including frame where Javascript is called

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to reload an entire frameset using Javascript onload() event?

```
function logout() {
    /* ... */
    // reload entire frame
    top.location.reload();
}

<body onload="logout()">
```

This cause all frames to reload but the URL of the frame where this was called didn't changed to the URL specified in the framset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understood it, you want to reload each frame in a frameset using the original URL as stated in <frame src="...">.

This little function can do that (put it into the document holding the frameset):

```
this.reloadChildFrames = function()
{
    var allFrames = document.getElementsByTagName("frame");
    for (var i = 0; i < allFrames.length; i++)
    {
        var f = allFrames[i];
        f.contentDocument.location = f.src;
    }
}
```

You are then able to call that function from within any child frame:

```
top.reloadChildFrames()
```

Of course, this can only work when all frames come from [the same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).